# Solve $ \left|\{ X \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\} \wedge \{1,4\} \subseteq X \wedge \{1,5\} \nsubseteq X \}\right| $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Solve $ \left|\{ X \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\} \wedge \{1,4\} \subseteq X \wedge \{1,5\} \nsubseteq X \}\right| $ = A

I tried solving it by saying:

when $n <= 3$, then $|A| = 0$

when $n = 4$, then $|A| = 4$ (just $\{1,4\}\, , \{1,2,4\}\, , \{1,3,4\}\, , \{1,2,3,4\}$ )

when $n = 5$, then $|A| = 4$ (just $\{1,4\}\, , \{1,2,4\}\, , \{1,3,4\}\, , \{1,2,3,4\}$ )

when $n > 6$, then $|A| = 2^{n-3}$ (because $1,4$ are always in the group, and $5$ is not. which means we check always the possibilites for all the others $2^{n-3}$ elements that are left.

what do you guys think?

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: You are correct. You can simplify it just a little. You don’t need to split the cases $n=5$ and $n\ge 6$: when $n=5$ there are still $n-3$ free choices.